# Slicer Relationship issue with data over date and time series

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Trying to create a dashboard with a selection of different releases, and would like to show Throughput over time.

I can display data over timeseries successfully, however I am now looking to add a slicer filter detailing the name of said Releases.
When one of the releases on the slicer is clicked, I would like it to filter to the relevant time and date in my visual.

My table structure is as follows

Data table =
90th Percentile Response Time
95th Percentile Response Time
Average Response Time (s)
Datacentre
Date
DateTime
HTTPCode
Method
Server
Standard Deviation
Throughput (TPM)
Time

Release table =
Release(name)
Date
TimeStart
TimeEnd

Dates table =
Date
Day Name
Day of Week
Month
Month Name
Short Day
Short Month
Start of Month
Year

Time Table =
Hour
HourMinute
Minute
Time
TimeIndex

I would like to click on [Example of dashboard and releases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXkSU.png) of one of the Releases in the table, and it filter accordingly.

I have included a screenshot of my tables [Tables in Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZbQA.png)

As well as the relationships I currently have [Table Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUF2V.png) but to summarize - in the main data table there is a relationship between MainDataTable-date to Dates-Date, as well as MainDataTable-Time Time-Time.

Release Schedule then has a relationship from Release Schedule-Date to Dates-Date, Release Schedule-TimeStart to Time-Time and Release Schedule-TimeEnd to Time-Time

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Measure similar to this:

```
Release data count = 
  var cntNormal = COUNTROWS('Your Data Table')
  var cntFiltered = 
    SUMX(
      'Release Schedule',
      COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
          'Your Data Table',
          'Your Data Table'[Date] = CALCULATE(MIN('Release Schedule'[Date])) &&
          'Your Data Table'[Time] >= CALCULATE(MIN('Release Schedule'[TimeStart])) &&
          'Your Data Table'[Time] <= CALCULATE(MIN('Release Schedule'[TimeEnd]))
        )
      )
    )

  RETURN IF( ISFILTERED('Release Schedule'), cntFiltered, cntNormal )
```

Then add this measure to your chart as a Visual Filter in the Filter pane on the right, and set it to `is not blank`.